# Scanner issue "java.util.NoSuchElementException" - Scanner can't be used in method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a Roleplay Game for the Console, it's my first Project.

Until now everything does work but I got a Scanner issue there. In the method, fight(), the scanner always spits out a error message, which I don't understand.

I already tried to make it a class variable and use it more than once, even so tried to change the variable names, everything failed.

Would like to have some help, thank you.

```
public class RPG {
// CLASS ATTRIBUTES
Player player;

private static Weapon[][] weaponArsenal = new Weapon[4][2];
private static Armor[][] armorArsenal = new Armor[4][2];
private static Enemy[][] enemies = new Enemy[4][2];
private static Skill[] skills = new Skill[7];

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// MAIN
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  // welcome
  System.out.print("Hello Player, welcome to the Console RPG!\nHow can I call you?\n\nUsername:\n>");
  String playerUsername = scan.next();
  // init weapon / armor / skill / enemy
  initWeapon();
  initArmor();
  initSkill();
  initEnemy();

  // init player
  player = new Player(playerUsername, 100, weaponArsenal[0][0], armorArsenal[0][0]);

  // info
  System.out.println("...\n\nThis is a great name, " + player.getName() + "!\n" +
          "You'll get the beginner equipment at first.\n");

  // print info, wait for input clear screen
  player.info();
  waitForEnter();
  clearScreen();

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

  // tutorial
  System.out.println("Let's show you how to play!...\n");
  System.out.println("Your first fight is against " + enemies[0][0].getName() + "!");

  fight(player, enemies[0][0]);


  scan.close();
} // end_main

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// init methods
static void initWeapon(){
  // [rarity][weapon]

  // default
  weaponArsenal[0][0] = new Weapon("Fist", 5, 0);

  // common
  weaponArsenal[1][0] = new Weapon("Dagger (common)", 8, 50);
  weaponArsenal[1][1] = new Weapon("Staff (common)", 12, 80);

  // rare
  weaponArsenal[2][0] = new Weapon("Dagger (rare)", 15, 120);
  weaponArsenal[2][1] = new Weapon("Staff (rare)", 19, 180);

  // epic
  weaponArsenal[3][0] = new Weapon("Dagger (epic)", 20, 210);
  weaponArsenal[3][1] = new Weapon("Staff (epic)", 25, 290);

} // end_initWeapon
static void initArmor(){
  // init armor

  // default
  armorArsenal[0][0] = new Armor("Cloth", 3);

  // common
  armorArsenal[1][0] = new Armor("Leather (common)", 5);
  armorArsenal[1][1] = new Armor("Bronze (common)", 8);

  // rare
  armorArsenal[2][0] = new Armor("Leather (rare)", 10);
  armorArsenal[2][1] = new Armor("Bronze (rare)", 13);

  // epic
  armorArsenal[3][0] = new Armor("Leather (epic)", 15);
  armorArsenal[3][1] = new Armor("Bronze (epic)", 20);
} // end_initArmor

static void initSkill(){

} // end init_Skill
static void initEnemy(){
  // enemies[difficulity][level]

  // baby
  enemies[0][0] = new Enemy("Goblin Baby", 100, weaponArsenal[0][0], armorArsenal[0][0], 5);
  enemies[0][1] = new Enemy("Orc Baby", 120, weaponArsenal[1][0], armorArsenal[1][0], 10);

  // normal
  enemies[1][0] = new Enemy("Goblin Normal", 130, weaponArsenal[0][0], armorArsenal[0][0], 10);
  enemies[1][1] = new Enemy("Orc Normal", 150, weaponArsenal[1][0], armorArsenal[1][0], 15);

  // hard
  enemies[2][0] = new Enemy("Goblin Hard", 160, weaponArsenal[0][0], armorArsenal[0][0], 15);
  enemies[2][1] = new Enemy("Orc Normal", 180, weaponArsenal[1][0], armorArsenal[1][0], 20);

  // extreme
  enemies[3][0] = new Enemy("Goblin Extreme", 190, weaponArsenal[0][0], armorArsenal[0][0], 20);
  enemies[3][1] = new Enemy("Orc Normal", 220, weaponArsenal[1][0], armorArsenal[1][0], 25);

} // end_initEnemy

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

// other methods
static void fight(Player player, Enemy enemy) { // TO-DO, error code in switch
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int cases = 0;

  do {
    System.out.println("Please make a choice...\n" +
    "1: Attack\n" +
    "2: Skill\n");
     cases = scan.nextInt();

    switch(cases){
      // case 1: attack, case 2: skill
      case 1:
        player.attack(enemy);
        enemy.attack(player);
    }

  } while (player.getHp() <= 0 || enemy.getHp() <= 0);
  scan.close();
} // end_fight
}
```

// [...]

I want different methods, with more than one scanning input, but I always get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at RPG.fight(RPG.java:133)
    at RPG.main(RPG.java:47)
```

C:\Users\yusuf\Desktop\txtRPG>

Comment: When you have a scanner using System.in and you close that scanner you also close System.in and you can't open that again. So use one scanner, not 2, and keep it open as long as you need input. In your case you could send the scanner opened in main() as an argument to fight()

Comment: 133: cases = scan.nextInt();

Comment: Also, in main you want to use `nextLine()` rather than `next()` when reading from the scanner

Comment: Either you have more methods where you create `Scanner` instances and close them or your username contains a whitespace. There is currently no other way I see in your (current) code which causes this exception.

Comment: Thank you @JoakimDanielson, this help me trough!